# Red-shift formula

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, doppler-effect, redshift

What is the true redshift formula that we can use it in every question?

I somewhere read that it is:
$z= \frac{v}{c}$

and in another place it says:

$1+z = \sqrt\frac{c+v}{c-v}$ so $z = \sqrt\frac{c+v}{c-v} -1 $

In another place it says we use the second one when the v is comparable to c, but when is v comparable to c? what about problems that wants the velocity and we don't know if the v is comparable to c or not?

Thanks.

Comment: Please detail your notations. Are you sure about your tags? General relativity? Speed of light?

Comment: Expand your second expression for z to first order in $v/c$.

Comment: @fffred general relativity because the second formula is the relativistic formula for redshift. I also asked when the velocity is comparable to c (speed of light).

Comment: Any use? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift

Comment: @Farcher No. the formula I wrote is for Doppler redshift, not Gravitational redsihft.

Comment: It is not about general relativity, I fear, but only special relativity. And this question needs to define clearly c and z. Please edit the question accordingly. Some context would be useful: is it about light for instance ?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196025/gravitational-redshift-in-a-general-stationary-metric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "true" redshift formula is :
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{\lambda_r}{\lambda_e} \equiv 1+z
\end{equation}
This is the only one you can use in "every question"... But it might not be the most effective to use!

If the redshift is due to a relativistic source moving along the line of sight of the observer with a velocity $v$ ($v>0$ for receding motion), then, one finds that ($\beta \equiv v/c$) :
\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\lambda_r}{\lambda_e} = 1+z = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}}
\end{equation}

(This can be shown by calculating the interval at which "bips" emitted from a moving source at $v=0$ and a know frequency $f_e$ are seen by a fixed target, using Lorentz transformations)

For low velocities ($\beta \to 0$) :
\begin{equation}
1+z = \sqrt{\dfrac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}} = 1+\dfrac{v}{c} + \mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}\right)
\end{equation}

Then in this case, $z \simeq v/c$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the approximate formula $z= \frac{v}{c}$ and see what you get for the speed $v$.
If you get an answer greater than about say $ \frac{c}{10}$ then use the formula $z = \sqrt\frac{c+v}{c-v} -1$

Comment: I would value some feedback on the down vote.  I have assumed that $z$ is the fractional change in wavelength/frequency and that the motion is along the line joining the source and observer.  The OP was unsure as to which formula to use when the value of the speed $v$ is to be found.  I have corrected my typo to $\frac {c}{10}$ which then gives a difference of about $\frac 12 \%$ between the two formulae at that speed.